# How to Display / Restrict the part of many2one records to list in odoo?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

view.xml

```xml
<field name="planning_id"/>
<field name="employee"/>
<field name="job_position" />
```

I want to display the job_position which is matched with the similar companies of planning_id(`job_position.company_id=planning_id.company`). 
I tried with domain but its not working.

```xml
<field name="job_position" domain="'company_id'=planning_id.company_id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a related field to have the company in the same model, so, in the .py of your model:

```
company_id = fields.Many2one(related='planning_id.company_id')
```

Then, in the view:

```
<field name="job_position" domain="[('company_id', '=', company_id)]"/>
```